# Json to Python single list of values and Lables

Tags: python, json, arraylist, charts

I have a rest API returning a json document. In order to create a chart, I need to extract two list of values.

```
age_list = [45,46,47,48,.....67] and balance list as 
value_list = [3210000,3434700,....13291205]
```

---- I could print the values, but want to know how to create list of values.

```
import json
jsonStr =  '{"items":[{"age":46,"balance":3210000},{"age":47,"balance":3434700},{"age":48,"balance":3675129},{"age":49,"balance":3932388},{"age":50,"balance":4207655},{"age":51,"balance":4502191},{"age":52,"balance":4817344},{"age":53,"balance":5154559},{"age":54,"balance":5515378},{"age":55,"balance":5901454},{"age":56,"balance":6314556},{"age":57,"balance":6756575},{"age":58,"balance":7229535},{"age":59,"balance":7735602},{"age":60,"balance":8277095},{"age":61,"balance":8856491},{"age":62,"balance":9476446},{"age":63,"balance":10139797},{"age":64,"balance":10849583},{"age":65,"balance":11609053},{"age":66,"balance":12421687},{"age":67,"balance":13291205}],"hasMore":false,"limit":25,"offset":0,"count":22,"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://fp7cb75hkszpygo-db202201121316.adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/admin/rest-rc1/rc1/45/3000000/0.07"},{"rel":"describedby","href":"https://fp7cb75hkszpygo-db202201121316.adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/admin/metadata-catalog/rest-rc1/rc1/45/3000000/item"},{"rel":"first","href":"https://fp7cb75hkszpygo-db202201121316.adb.us-sanjose-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/admin/rest-rc1/rc1/45/3000000/0.07"}]}'

pythonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
for i in pythonObj['items']:
    print( '\'',i['age'],'\'',',')    
for i in pythonObj['items']:
    print( '\'',i['balance'],'\'',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to separate the data like this? There's probably a reason that age and balance are coupled. It's generally not a good idea to separate coupled data. For instance, what if you sort the `age_list`? Then the balances are no longer going to correspond to the ages. If that's not important, then disregard.

You can use a single `for` loop over the dictionaries in the `items` list, and accumulate into two lists:

```py
ages = []
balances = []
for dictionary in pythonObj['items']:
    ages.append(dictionary['age'])
    balances.append(dictionary['balance'])
```

This is called the **accumulator pattern** and is ubiquitous in programming. I recommend checking out the official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of the language.